# JoinConference with the Lync 2013 client SDK in UI suppression mode

Tags: sdk, lync, conference, modality

I'm working on a project that uses the Lync 2013 client SDK in UI suppression mode to show a custom UI for Skype.  I am able to call the ConversationManager.AddConversation() method and connect to IM, audio and video just fine for 1 on 1 calls.

Now, I would like to call the ConversationManager.JoinConference(conferenceUri) to join an online meeting.  I am using the uri for a scheduled meeting and I format it like this:

conf:sip:aweston@meet.dev.domain.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:6OHB2XXX?required-media=audiovideo

The call seems to connect but after going through some state changes it just goes to Disconnected.

If I join the same meeting using the standard S4B client, the meeting connects just fine so I think the meeting and the connectivity is all setup  and working ok.

I have looked for samples on how to do this here …

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933140.aspx

And also in the SDK here …
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\samples

I'm starting to look at the S4B logs here …
.\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\Tracing

But I'm not really sure what I 'm looking at there.

Here is a log of the calls that I'm making.
Any suggestions or samples you have that are doing a similar thing would be most appreciated.

Thanks

--Andy

11:01:11 PM SkypeService: **_lyncClient_ConversationAdded**
11:01:11 PM SkypeService: Conversation: Inactive,  Modality: Disconnected, Video: None,  Audio: None, Count: 1
11:01:11 PM SkypeService: ListenToConversation
11:01:17 PM SkypeService: ConferenceId: sip:aweston@meet.dev.domain.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:6OHB2XXX
11:01:17 PM SkypeService: Conversation: Inactive,  Modality: Disconnected, Video: None,  Audio: None, Count: 1
11:01:17 PM SkypeService: Conversation_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, RemoveParticipant
11:01:17 PM SkypeService: Conversation_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, Merge
11:01:17 PM SkypeService: **Conversation_ParticipantAdded**
11:01:20 PM SkypeService: Conversation_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, Park
11:01:20 PM SkypeService: CallModality_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  True, Connect
11:01:20 PM SkypeService: AudioChannel_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  True, Start
...
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: CallModality_StateChanged:  **Connecting**
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: Conversation: Inactive,  Modality: Connecting, Video: None,  Audio: None, Count: 1
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: AudioChannel_StateChanged:  **Connecting**
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: Conversation: Inactive,  Modality: Connecting, Video: None,  Audio: None, Count: 1
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: VideoChannel_StateChanged:  **Connecting**
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: Conversation: Inactive,  Modality: Connecting, Video: None,  Audio: None, Count: 1
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: Conversation_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, AddParticipant
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: Conversation_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, Merge
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: SharingModality_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, Connect
11:01:24 PM SkypeService: SharingModality_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  True, Connect
11:01:25 PM SkypeService: Conversation_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, RemoveParticipant
11:01:25 PM SkypeService: VideoChannel_ActionAvailabilityChanged:  False, Start
**11:01:30 PM SkypeService: CallModality_StateChanged:  Disconnected**

Detailed Error ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cccp"
         xmlns:mscp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/rtc/2005/08/cccpextensions"
         C3PVersion="1"
         to="sip:aweston@meet.dev.DOMAIN.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:6OHB2E3Y"
         from="sip:aweston@dev.DOMAIN.com"
         requestId="935284871552">
  <addUser>
    <conferenceKeys confEntity="sip:aweston@meet.dev.DOMAIN.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:6OHB2E3Y"/>
    <ci:user xmlns:ci="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:conference-info"
             entity="sip:aweston@dev.DOMAIN.com">
      <ci:roles>
        <ci:entry>attendee</ci:entry>
      </ci:roles>
      <ci:endpoint entity="{F4E183FE-5304-4281-ABAE-0A5EE56A7175}"
                   xmlns:msci="http://schemas.microsoft.com/rtc/2005/08/confinfoextensions"/>
    </ci:user>
  </addUser>
</request>

Response Data:
504  Server time-out
ms-diagnostics:  1065;reason="Federation is disabled";domain="meet.dev.DOMAIN.com";source="sip.dev.DOMAIN.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conference link suggests that audio/video is required but your log is showing that there is no Audio or video devices connected.  Try the following conference link remember to include the ? at the end conf:sip:aweston@meet.dev.domain.com;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:6OHB2XXX?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried your idea, same result.  After JoinConference, in the Conversation_Added() event, I'm not sure what to call, I've tried AddParticipant and BeginConnect but I keep getting Connecting ... disconnected.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything, calling conversationManage,JoinConference(conferenceuri) should be sufficient. Are you handling any of the events of the resulting conversation and if you are how so?

Comment: I'm seeing the ParticipantAdded event for myself but that is all. The modalities are all disconnected.  If I join the conference in the S4B client with a second user, it seems like I have 2 separate conversations.

Comment: It's a long shot but recently I have seen anti virus software affecting conference joins (Norton in particular) is there a chance you can disable your anit virus briefly just to rule it out?

Comment: I turned on Windows Event Logging and I got a good error message from my request:  **ms-diagnostics:  1065;reason="Federation is disabled"**.  I'm looking at server side configuration now but I'm wondering why the S4B client works fine but my API call fails.

Comment: Did that message also include source and  domain values?  It seems odd that you are getting federation issues here and not in the normal client.

Comment: Added error details ... this is a dev environment that was recently setup for us.

Comment: Success!  The keys to making this work were 1) adding that lone ? to the end of the link,  2) stripping "meet." out of the domain name when calling the API, and 3) enabling Federation in the S4B control panel on the server, thanks!